# Standard representation of $\frak S_4$

Tags: representation-theory

On p. 18 of Representation Theory: A First Course, Fulton and Harris write

> The character of the standard representation is $\chi_V = (3, 1, 0, -1, -1)$. Note that $|\chi_V| = 1$ so $V$ is irreducible.

However, when I compute, I get ${1\over 24}(9 + 1 + 1 + 1) = 1/2$. Should I not be dividing by $24 = |\frak S_4|$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not multiplying by the number of elements in each conjugacy class.

Comment: I see, just found a webpage detailing that mistake, thanks. I include the webpage for completeness: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group:S4